# How to map multiple social logins to a single user's account?

Tags: design-patterns, azure, oauth, identity

I'm creating an app backend using Azure Mobile Services. The app makes use of the Azure Mobile Services identities(Microsoft, Facebook, Google and Twitter) as its alternative login/signup process. I create a new user profile the first time a user signs in, then if a user signs in using a different social identity I want to automatically link it to the users existing profile/account.

**What is the common pattern or best practices used when linking multiple social identities to a single user?**

*The Method I'm thinking about using is:*

When the user logs in using a social identity I use the user object's *getIdentities()* function in Mobile Services server scripts to return an object with provider-specific data(userId and accessToken). I then use the users accessToken to retrieve the user's email address from the social API.

Once I have the user's email, do a check to see if the email address exists in the database and if it is associated with a different userId(eg. Twitter:userId), then link the current user object's userId(eg. Facebook:userId) to the account.

**How do I add the "login scope" to Mobile Services identities that requests permission to let me get the user's email address?**  (eg. Facebook's '*/me?scope=email*')

**Is this a suitable solution and what issues should I consider using this method?**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended permissions on the email field. The user must allow you to see this and you cannot get the e-mail addresses of the users friends.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can do this if you are using Facebook connect by passing scope=email in the get string of your call to the Auth Dialog.

I'd recommend using an SDK instead of file_get_contents as it makes it far easier to perform the Oauth authentication.

Live Version is here: http://facebook.init.me/php-get-email-address

```
    <?php

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $initMe["appId"],
  'secret' => $initMe["appSecret"],
));

$facebook->setAccessToken($initMe["accessToken"]);
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    print_r($user_profile["email"]);
}
```

?>

If you are using a windows phone you can access phone Token such that you know the login comes from the same phone. Scrool down to  PrimaryToken http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: You can also look at this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/multi-factor-authentication/